# Current Time Stamp is not returning?

Tags: timestamping

I have a Text field called NARRATIVE using long/text.  I want to place a timestamp in the field for each entry a person makes but when my toggle button is clicked it timestamps in the field but does not return so I can timestamp something else on the next line . Instead the timestamp overwrites the last one.
Here is my code:

`Private Sub Toggle344_Click()`

```
Me.NARRATIVE = Now()
```

End Sub

This is what I want it to do each time the toggle button is pushed:

```
5/25/2017 2:31:10 PM DL CHECK/TX/222222222

5/25/2017 2:34:22 PM CONSENT TO SEARCH VEHICLE

5/25/2017 2:35:30 PM MARIJ FOUND UNDER FRONT SEAT

5/25/2017 2:41:17 PM SUBJECT DETAINED
```

EACH EVENT IS TIMESTAMPED AS IT HAPPENS BUT WITH MY CODE IT JUST OVERWRITES
THE FIRST TIME STAMP AND DOES NOT GO DOWN TO THE NEXT LINE LIKE I WANT.
HELP !
THANKS IN ADVANCE
gljones

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consult your local PC shop, it seems your caps lock key is jammed.

Comment: What programming language is this about? Please add the accordant tag so that it reaches the right audience.

Comment: I just had someone help me and we got it working.  Thanks !

Comment: Great. Would you mind adding the solution so that people who need that in the future can benefit from that?

Comment: Here is the solution to my timestamp problem courtesy of Dirk Goldgar, MS Access MVP                                                                                                                                                                                                   Private Sub Command344_Click()
 With Me.NARRATIVE
        If Len(.Value & vbNullString) = 0 Then
            .Value = Now() & " "
        Else
            .Value = .Value & vbCrLf & Now() & " "
        End If
        .SetFocus
        .SelStart = Len(.Text)
        .SelLength = 0
    End With

End Sub